# CushyCMS is unable to connect to the FTP server - "End of file"

Tags: ftp, connection, content-management-system, hosting

I hosted a simply website on my domain five years ago (in 2018). I connected CushyCMS to this website, and it was working fine. However, now it seems that CushyCMS is unable to establish an FTP connection with my server. Every attempt to edit a page on the site results in the following error message:

```
End of File 
The file being transferred unexpectedly finished
There may be a temporary server problem, please try again later.
```

I tried connecting to my server via FTP using FileZilla, and it worked without any issues. I was able to connect and upload files without any problems.

What steps can I take to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In my case, the issue was with the hosting configuration. The provider had added a new option that blocked HTTPS requests from other countries by default, and it simply required unchecking this parameter. The hosting is in Poland, while the CMS is from Australia.